How to link excel file to powerpoint without going through exact file path
Hi I'm looking for a way to conduct the same analysis every month but in different folders each year.
I have charts and tables in multiple excel files, and these charts and tables are linked to different slides in a powerpoint file. Every month I will update the values in excel and the corresponding charts and tables will be updated in the powerpoint. However, a different user conducts the analysis every year and if I duplicate the files into another folder, the ppt links will break as the source files (excel) do not follow the same path anymore.

There are too many charts and graphs to individually copy and paste over to the ppt every year, and I wouldn't want them working the analysis in someone else's folder. Is there a way to go about this efficiently?

For some types of files, PPT will accept "pathless" links. For example if you have an image and the PPT file stored in the same folder, then link to the image, you can move the image and PPT file pretty much anywhere (cloud excepted) and so long as they're in the same folder, the links will work.
Links to Excel content, though, are OLE links; these require a full path. Some versions of PPT will look in the current PPT's folder if the linked Excel file isn't in the expected location; if your version supports this, you could copy all of the necessary files to a new location each month, then rename the previous month's folder before opening the new version.
Another option is to use VBA to Search/Replace link paths. There are a couple examples on the PPT FAQ site that I maintain:
https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00759_Search_-_Replace_to_change_OLE_link_paths.htm
https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00773_Batch_Search_and_Replace_for_Hyperlinks-_OLE_links-_movie_links_and_sound_links.htm
